# Populate a text box from a pulldown box in acrobat dc using java

Tags: javascript, java, loops, acrobat, keystroke

Question: How can I populate a text box using selections from a pulldown box in Acrobat DC.

Work: I was able to find this on the inter webs:

```
if (!event.willCommit){this.getField("Text1").value=event.changeEx;}
```

This works fine but I would like it to populate every time a selection is made. The pull down box is set to commit immediately.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where did you add that line of code?

Comment: Format/Custom/Custom Keystroke Script of the pulldown box.

Comment: As you have set immediate commit, you would have to execute the script on commit. Therefore, you can just set the field value, without the need for testing whether it does not commit.